# A recieved text message that was never sent on iPhone

Tags: mobile, iphone, sms

My girlfriend asked me why I texted her at 2:30 am. But I went to bed at 2am and that message was not recorded on my phone. She had an iPhone and I have a Samsung Galaxy S9. She sent me a picture of the text and yes in fact it was a message from my number but I never sent it. Can it be an old message that was sent automatically from my number? An iPhone glitch perhaps? I would like to know the reason.

Comment: It is trivial to spoof the sender's number when texting. We get this question a lot.

Comment: Your girl friend might contact her mobile network provider to track the origin of that text message.

Comment: Is it possible that this was a message that you tried to send her around Valentines day?  If so, then it may be related to a server issue at Syniverse, which is being reported today in the media.  See https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/11/why-168149-valentines-day-text-messages-arrived-in-november/.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say this is an glitch or something like that. Basically this sounds like a spoofed text message. This technique is called "[Caller id spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID_spoofing)" and can be achieved in numerous ways.

> Caller ID spoofing is the practice of causing the telephone network to indicate to the receiver of a call that the originator of the call is a station other than the true originating station. For example, a caller ID display might display a phone number different from that of the telephone from which the call was placed.

So if someone knows your number he can text your girlfiend with it. Her phone believes this message came from your number and puts the message under your name. There are some free apps or websites where anyone can achieve this.